# Removing item from session array Jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a table containing a row for each element in an array. I am trying to remove the element when the delete image is clicked (the image's id is `deleteRowButton`). At the moment nothing happens when you click the image, however if I remove the `var index` line, the table row will fade out as expected (but of course the array element is not removed.

```
$(document).on('click', '#deleteRowButton', function() {
    var index = $(this).closest('tr').attr(id); 
   //Set index to the id of table row (number corresponding to their position in the array)
    remove_index(index); 
    $(this).closest("tr").fadeOut('slow');
    return false;
});

function remove_index(value) {
    $.post("./remove_array_item.php", {index:value});
}
```

Here is my code in `remove_array_item.php` to remove the array element:

```
<?php  
include("./config/init.php"); //Contains session_start() etc. 

$index = $_POST['index']; //index variable passed in
$ca = $_SESSION["objColl"]; //get array from session variable
$ca->delLineItem($index); //delete item of array at index
$_SESSION["objColl"] = $ca; //store array as session variable 
?>
```

So what I am wondering is:

1. Why does the jquery function stop firing if I include:

`var index = $(this).closest('tr').attr(id);`

i.e. if I comment it out, the function will make the table row fade out.

2. What is wrong with my function in `remove_array_item.php` because even when I remove the `var index` and just pass a value for the index like so

`remove_index(1);`

It still does not remove the item from the array and so when I refresh the page, the item is back in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Change `var index = $(this).closest('tr').attr(id);` to `var index = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');`
You forgot the quotes around `id`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you made a mistake by binding on click event to an Id, where as you will have multiple rows.
You need to share the HTML to clarify this issue.

A wild guess. Change the #deleteRowButton (id) to .deleteRowButton (class).

Also note that attr() function only accept string as parameter.

$(this).closest('tr').attr("id");